# I'm trying to find a way to iterate through a list of game objects to find furthest object in the list. Then re iterate if path is blocked

Tags: unity, c#, algorithm, path-finding, navmesh

I've got the first part of the code working. It iterates and does a check through the gameobjects to find the furthest nav point to hit. Then it calculates path to see if its valid or not. Now I'm stuck. I want it to re iterate by omitting that value from the list of gameobjects and pick a new value and check it again to see if it is valid. Here is the code in question.

```
if (navMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance)
                {

                    furthestObject = FindFurthestObject(navPoints);
                    bool isPathValid =CheckForValidPath(furthestObject.transform.position);

                    if (isPathValid)
                    {
                        navMeshAgent.Warp(furthestObject.transform.position);
                        runFromLight = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GameObject navPoint = FindRandomSpawnPoint(navPoints);
                        runFromLight = false;
                        GameObject telePortParts = Instantiate(teleportParticleSystem, transform.position, transform.rotation);                            
                        navMeshAgent.Warp(navpoints[0].transform.position);
                    }
                }
```

And the code for iterating through the gameobject lists is here.

```
public GameObject FindFurthestObject(List <GameObject> gameObjects)
{
    float furthestDistance = 0;
    GameObject furthestObject = null;

    foreach(GameObject Object in gameObjects)
    {
        float objectDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Object.transform.position);

        if(objectDistance > furthestDistance)
        {
            furthestObject = Object;
            furthestDistance = objectDistance;
        }
    }

    return furthestObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a list of game objects called something like `gameObjectsCheck`. and make it a copy of your `navPoints` list, replace

```
furthestObject = FindFurthestObject(navPoints);
```

with

```
furthestObject = FindFurthestObject(gameObjectsCheck);
```

then, in your first code block, you should surround the entire thing after the initial if statement in a while loop using `!isValidPath` as it's break condition. this way you will keeping checking new objects until a valid path is found. you will need to create the `isValidPath` bool outside of the while loop, and set it to false as well, in order to start the while loop.

```
if (navMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance)
{
    bool isPathValid = false;
    while ( !isValidPath ) 
    {
        furthestObject = FindFurthestObject(gameObjectsCheck);       
        isPathValid=CheckForValidPath(furthestObject.transform.position);

...
```

lastly, when you check if a path is valid, in the `else` statement, as in when a valid path *is not* found, remove `furthestObject` from `gameObjectsCheck`.

in total, this will loop through the code checking whether the current furthest object has a valid path to it or not, and if it doesn't, it is removed from the list of objects you are checking using `FindFurthestObject`, which will then find the *next* furthest object, and check again with that object, repeating this process until a valid path is found.

Comment: Okay will definitely give it a try. Thanks. Just trying to wrap my head around it.